# Юридическая и интеллектуальная подкованность веб-мастера.

Tags: лицензирование

Меня интересуют вопросы, касающиеся услуг разработки сайта.

1. Если у меня есть сайт, и на нём конкретно цены и условия разработки, платёжные реквизиты, т.е. сайт ведёт коммерческую деятельность, но я как фрилансер не имею ИП, его обязательно открывать? Что будет если я продолжу заниматься этой деятельностью без ИП?
2. Как на счёт авторства? Если я написал уникальный скрипт, но это делал для заказчика, который оплатил мои услуги, а вдруг он захочет его продавать? Как меня обезопасить от этого, и чтобы я в случае его коммерческого использования, получал долю?
3. Что-нибудь ещё нужно знать, чтобы безопасно работать разработчиком сайтов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Сайт - это не организация и не ИП. А всего лишь виртуальная площадка. Если Вы персонально ведете коммерческую деятельность - имеет смысл зарегистрироваться. Иначе в теории продолжение деятельности наказуемо. Другой вопрос, что став ИП Вы берете на себя кучу обязательств. И их невыполнение тоже наказуемо (напр., если не будете вовремя подавать декларации в налоговую или будете подавать их некорректно). Вообще - лучше проконсультироваться с юристом.
2. Составить договор о проведении работ с указанием того, что написанное Вами остается Вашей интеллектуальной собственностью. Иначе доказать что-либо будет весьма трудно.
3. без понятия :-)